# Convert if 'with range' to switch statement

Tags: c#-4.0, if-statement, .net-4.0, switch-statement

Someone asked me today how to convert the following if statement to switch:

```
int i=5;
if(i>10)
{
   Do Something;
}
else
{
    Do Something else;
}
```

And I proposed that assuming i is an integer with only positive values:

```
int i=5;
switch(i)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10: Do Something else;
    break;
    case default: Do Something;
    break;
}
```

Is there any other, more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: [It doesn't seem so](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/792582d0-2e36-40e3-873e-2be18337d074/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing that in C#, you can try the following.

```
int range = (number - 1) / 10;

switch(range)
{
  case 0: 
       Console.WriteLine("1 to 10");
       break;
  case 1:
       Console.WriteLine("11 to 20");
       break;
 //.,......
  default:
       break;
}
```

Not really sure how much clear it would be, IMO, the above approach would reduce the code readability, its better if you use `if-else` for the range checking. Also the above would work only if the range is constant.

Answer (score 1):

First, note your two code examples (as were originally written) were not equivalent:

- You're not `Do[ing] Something Else` when `i==10` in your `switch` example.
- But the original `if` code was checking on `i>10` (as opposed to `i>=10`).
- So `case 10:` should be explicitly included in your list of `case`s that fall through to `Do Something Else`.

To answer your question, I believe in some languages (eg pascal, objective C, I think?) a *range* similar to this is allowed:

```
switch(i)
{
    case 1-10: // or is it "case 1 .. 10" ?
        Do Something else;
        break;
    case default: 
        Do Something;
        break;
}
```

But this is ***not*** supported in C#.  Refer the very final point in the code discussion regarding "stacking" of case labels here [MSDN switch(C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)